# Run cypress test in a docker container?

Tags: docker, cypress

How to run cypress test in a docker container ? I have created an account in docker and then as per link `https://hub.docker.com/u/cypress` and run the following command from my folder location in Desktop/Windows 10 : `docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:3.4.0`

But I am getting following error. How can I resolve the error, can someone please advise.

docker: Error response from daemon: create $PWD: "$PWD" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your OS you need to change `$PWD` to reflect your current folder (ex: $(pwd) on linux or MacOS).

If you can't figure it out just use an absolute path instead of $PWD, just like the docker hint indicates.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am running in `Windows` so may I know what should i replace instead $PWD ?

Comment: what version of windows? are you using powershell or just normal command prompt?

Comment: try %CD% or %cd%

Comment: Sure I will try that let you know.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question in comment, I have accepted this answer.

Comment: Appreciate that reply :) ..my question is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463893/why-running-cypress-via-docker-command-cypress-type-getting-undefined