# While running cypress via docker command, cypress type() getting undefined

Tags: docker, cypress

While running the cypress test using below docker command from windows 10 command prompt, the below error occurs.

`docker run -it -v %cd%:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:3.4.0`

But while running the cypress test by `npm run cy:test-uattest` script from windows command prompt all the test run successfully. Any idea why the `cy.type()` command becomes 'undefined' while running the docker command.

`cy.get('input[name="firstInput"]').type(Cypress.env('firstNumber'));`

Below is my Cypress.env.json file

```
{
  "numTestsKeptInMemory": 3,
  "firstNumber":"1000"
}
```

Error while running the docker command:

```
CypressError: cy.type() can only accept a String or Number. You passed in: 'undefined'
      at Object.cypressErr (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:84963:11)
      at Object.throwErr (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:84916:18)
      at Object.throwErrByPath (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:84947:17)
      at Context.type (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:71800:16)
      at Context.<anonymous> (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:80518:21)
      at https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:80223:33
      at tryCatcher (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:134216:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:132234:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:132291:18)
      at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:132328:10)
      at Async._drainQueue (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:129145:12)
      at Async._drainQueues (https://someurl.net/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:129150:10)
      at <anonymous>
```

Comment: it looks like it cannot find your Cypress.env.json. Did you place it next to  cypress.json?

Comment: Yes, while running using the `npm run cy:test-uattest` all of the UI test run successfully without any issues..

Comment: Can you run the following and post what you get? `docker run -it -v %cd%:/e2e -w /e2e --entrypoint ls cypress/included:3.4.0 -lart`

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    87 Feb 27 11:26 cypress.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   125 Feb 27 15:33 Cypress.env.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 64736 Feb 27 15:43 package-lock.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   558 Feb 28 02:14 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2706 Feb 28 02:38 README.md
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65536 Feb 29 07:12 node_modules
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Feb 29 07:12 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Feb 29 07:13 cypress
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Feb 29 11:06 ..`

Comment: I could see it is listing `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   125 Feb 27 15:33 Cypress.env.json`

Comment: weird. try 2 more things: 1. Output the file and make sure it looks good: `docker run -it -v %cd%:/e2e -w /e2e --entrypoint cat cypress/included:3.4.0 Config.env.json`. 2. Move your variables in cypress.json and see if it picks them up from there.

Comment: After running the command it displays as .. `cat: Config.env.json: No such file or directory`

Comment: :) my bad, typo: Cypress.env.json, not Config.env.json

Comment: Yes i was about to say that....

Comment: It is listing ..{
  "numTestsKeptInMemory": 3,
  "firstNumber":"1000"
}

Comment: and the 2nd part? is that working?

Comment: No, the same error is getting even after giving values in cypress.json file.

Comment: in your package.json, what is the definition of "cy:test-uattest"?

Comment: cy:test-uattest": "cypress run --spec cypress/integration/addUser/**/*"

Comment: it's really strange and I am out of ideas to test :) I suggest you pass the env variables on the command line to docker un for now just to proceed. I have a feeling there is a typo somewhere or some hidden character given that you are on Windows.

Comment: Ok I will try that, but how do i give env variables in command line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, this needs more investigation.

In the meantime, you can use environment variables:

Create a file `.env` (name is not important, as long as you use the same in the next step) with the following contents:

```
CYPRESS_numTestsKeptInMemory=3
CYPRESS_firstNumber=1000
```

Run your tests in docker with:

```
docker run -it -v %cd%:/e2e -w /e2e --env-file .env cypress/included:3.4.0
```

Comment: Is this correct ? I have my environment file name as `cypress.env.json` and the command follows  `docker run -it -v %cd%:/e2e -w /e2e --env-file cypress.env cypress/included:3.4.0'

Comment: The environment file is not json. You can name it the way you want as long as you use the same name in the docket run command and the contents of the file are as above (according to the official documentation)

Comment: I have tried as suggested, created a new file but still not working

Comment: I need to be able to reproduce this in order to fix it. If you can find a way to give me access to the sources then hopefully I can find out what's wrong with it.